# How well is biofeedback understood?

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request, consciousness, neuroimaging, biofeedback

From an [answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/155/4736) to the question [Research suggesting conscious control over brain region activation?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/96/research-suggesting-conscious-control-over-brain-region-activation?rq=1) I have learned:

> »[S]ubjects become better at up-regulating or down-regulating
>   activation in specific brain regions by attending to feedback-- even
>   moreso than subjects who do not receive biofeedback. This is reflected
>   both in the fMRI images and subjective reports from the subjects.«

Given this as a fact: How well is it understood? Which mechanisms are believed to be at work? I assume the fMRI scans mainly indicate *that* a specific brain region is more or less active but not *why* so. "Why so" could mean:

- By which mechanisms inside the region?
- By which influence by other regions?
- By which learned practice?
- How are the immediate causes (of higher activity) related to the fact that the subject pays attention to the feedback?
- How does consciousness come into play?

My question is: **Which of these questions do already have a (partial) answer?**